# rig control movement not moving along axis

Tags: rigging

how do we solve this where the movement of a ctrl from a rig moves along axis ( Z go up, X go left, etc). Right now, when i adjust through graph editor , going Z isn't going up but going up left, as shown in picture. Is the the pose of the rig itself is at fault ? do i need to make all my characters on T pose?[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the the pose of the rig itself is at fault ? do i need to make all my characters on T pose?

Well, the reason that the bone's Z axis points the way it does is because of the pose; and potentially, in a T pose, it would point straight up rather than diagonally up and out.

But this isn't a fault, and no, you don't need to make your characters T-posed.  This is just the way that bones (and objects, for that matter) work, and it's not a problem for animators.

Transforms, including keyframed transforms, are stored in the local space of the bone/object.  They are not world space or pose space.  If you have a bone oriented at a diagonal, its space will be rotated in relationship to world space or pose space.

That's okay.  How can we move the bone up in world Z?  In the viewport, with default global orientation, g z move mouse confirm; then keyframe location.

Would it be possible to have a bone that was both rotated (as an A-pose IK hand control) and which was aligned with pose space?  It would be.  We could create a new bone, aligned with world axes, parent our IK control to it, and then animate the new parent rather than our original control:

[image]

newParent's axes are aligned with the armature, so its local space is the same as its pose space, and if we adjust its Z location keyframes, we'll be moving it straight up and down.  oldControl will follow because of parenting.  (And so long as we don't rotate the armature, pose space will be in the same axes as world space.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think the problem is that you rigs bone normal/pole is facing the wrong direction heres an example of what I'm talking about
[image: demo of me playing with bones]

you just need to look for the bone thats causing the problem and change its roll factor
[image: me adjusting the bone roll factor]
or modify the IK Pole angle in the bone constrant tab.
[image: Me adjusting the pole angle]